# app's UI is not proper in a 220 dpi screen

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

hi I'm new in android developing and it's my first app.

I have made these folders in  address : app\src\main\res for supporting multiple phone and tablet screens and put proper dimens.xml  files in them.

- values-ldpi
- values-mdpi
- values-hdpi
- values-xhdpi
- values-xxhdpi
- values-xxxhdpi
- values-sw600dp
- values-sw768dp
- values-sw800dp

  1. first of all, are they complete or am I missing some screen sizes?
  2. second, I've tested the app on several devices and it's working fine and has proper user interface in all phones but on the Galaxy Grand Prime which has a 5 inch  540 x 960 pixels display that means 220 dpi. this phone using hdpi dimens but UI is a bit messy.

The following pictures may make my point better :

[image: proper UI , as it is shown in other devices]

Proper UI , as it is shown in other devices

VS

[image: UI in galaxy grand prime 220 dpi display]

UI in galaxy grand prime 220 dpi display

as UI is completely OK in other devices, I thought I should make a specific dimens.xml file for that kind of dpi, so I made values-sw220dp. but after that other phones used this dimens instead of hdpi dimens and problem got worse because UI was fine in the galaxy phone and was not proper in other hdpi displays. and now I don't know what should I do.

can anyone help me in this issue?

at last sorry because of flaws in my english , as you can guess I'm not a native.

Comment: You are mixing two kinds of resource selectors: mdpi, ldpi etc are based on dpi bucket, but sw600dp means "device with smallest screen width of 600dp" All phones have smallest side of a screen bigger than 220dp.

Comment: i made that for tablets , so what should i  do for supporting tablet screens?

Comment: i removed sw600dp , sw768dp and sw800dp xmls but it's still not proper on the mentioned device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> are they complete or i'm missing some screen sizes?

If you read the guides which I mentioned at the end of my answer you will find that there are very many possibilities of defining resources folders. I think nobody will want to implement all of them.

Usually you look at your app and then decide on maybe three or four screen sizes you want to support. I think "sw220dp" is important, if only to show a message that your app needs more space :-).

So there could well be three to five layout folders (sw220dp, sw320dp, maybe sw480dp, sw600dp, maybe sw820dp). If you need orientation-dependent layouts, then the number will be twice that much. (Why ? That's explained very well in the guides linked below)

You already know that there are different types of resources. Some of them do not depend on the screen resolution (e.g. layout files), some do (drawable resources).

So first of all you decide which screen sizes you want to support. Let's say they are "phone", "tablet" and "220dp". You create three layout files by the same name "my_activity.xml" and put them in three folders

- for the really small window: **res/layout-sw220dp**
- for the mobile phone: **res/layout-sw320dp**
- for the tablet: **res/layout-sw600dp**

By the way, "sw" stands for *smallest width* which is the minimum length of the screen, no matter what the orientation is currently.

Now let's assume you have created three different layout files and all of them contain an `ImageView` like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="24dp" 
    android:layout_height="24dp" 
    android:src="@drawable/my_picture" />
```

This is where the screen resolution comes into play: `24dp` is a size value in "density-independent pixels". It will be resolved depending on the screen resolution of the device. So you need different versions of *my_picture.png*, and for this you need different folders for drawables. They are named after the different categories for screen resolution so the runtime knows which png file to pick:

- **res/drawable/ldpi** (although I read somewhere you can skip that because the pictures will be scaled down from hdpi nicely)
- **res/drawable** (here go the resources for **res/drawable-mdpi** as well as every drawable resource for which resolution does not matter, e.g. drawables defined via xml files)
- **res/drawable-hdpi**
- **res/drawable-xhdpi**
- **res/drawable-xxhdpi**
- **res/drawable-xxxhdpi**

Helpful links:

[Providing Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

[Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: sorry i didn't get it very well. first i don't have any drawable in my app ( btw i already khew what to do with them). second , you suggest to change  mdpi, ldpi etc type to sw220dp, sw320dp etc and also use different layout instead of different dimens? and does those 5 sizes you mentioned enough to support all screens sizes?

Comment: @Mohsen Hesari - **-mdpi** etc. folders are for drawables, not for layout files. About layout files: you can also combine different layout files with different dimen values. And to make your app look good on all screens it's also very relevant what goes into the layout files. It's a question of combining all these parts in an optimal way. And yes, 5 screen sizes for one orientation are enough (or from a maintainability perspective even maybe too much) Read the linked guides and start your own experiments :)